# Html Bullet tag support in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile, textview

I have some issue regarding html tags which are not working in android textview could some one please suggest what to do in this regard.

Following are tags list:
1. Bullet tag.
2. Inner html tag.
3. Font tag.
4. Custom size tags ()

Comment: What's your error, show your effort

Comment: Whenever bullets are coming in numeric its unable to decode it and showing this as "." instead of numbers. for example its coming - 1. java, 2. android, 3. php................... but its showing in textview after parsing as - .java, .android, .php.